# Please explain this code list = ' '.join(i for i in list_text_from_file if not i in chars)

Tags: python, list, function

anyone explain the code within the join function i.e.

`(i for i in list_text_from_file if not i in chars)`

Comment: That is a _list comprehension_ which selects every item from `list_text_from_file` that isn't in `chars`.

Comment: Actually it's a generator expression, but they're similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `i` is `every character`, so `"".join(i for` is join the variable for every something. That something is `i in list_text_from_file`, so join `I` with `" "`, for every character in `list_text_from_file`. Next,  `if not i in chars`. This is saying that if the character, or `I` is also in `chars`, then do not join it with `" "`.

So, for every character in `list_text_from_file`, that is also not in `chars`, join it with `" "`.

If `list_text_from_file` is `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]`, and `chars` is `["C","E"]`. the result (`list`) would be `["A","B","D"]`

Answer (score 0):

It will return a string '' containing the special characters from **list_text_from_file** if this characters are not in your **chars** variable.

eg.

```
list_text_from_file = '321323132@#!%AafA'
chars ={'1','u','A'}
' '.join(i for i in list_text_from_file if not i in chars)
```

it will return:

```
'3 2 3 2 3 3 2 @ # ! % a f'
```